# Dundas Charts File Not Found

Tags: asp.net-ajax, iis-6, dundas, file-not-found, server-farm

I'm looking through a legacy system and have found that the Dundas charts throws a file not found exception quite often, but not all the time.

The system has multiple servers picking up requests and it has therefore set Dundas to run using a server farm configuration (Recommended by dundas [support](http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/WebChart2005/Image%20File%20Management.html)), as in this example:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ChartHttpHandler" value="Storage=file;Timeout=180;
     Url=http://dundas.com/temp/;Dir=\\dundas\wwwroot\inetpub\website\temp"/>
```

The chart images cannot be found a lot of the time, and I have a feeling it has to do with the multiple servers.

My charts have the properties: `ajaxzoomenabled="true" callbackstatecontent="All"`

The servers run IIS6 and our NBL affinity is set to use no affinity:

> No Affinity
>
> With No affinity, NLB does not associate clients with a particular
>   member. Every client request can be load balanced to any member. This
>   affinity provides the best performance but might disrupt clients with
>   established sessions, because subsequent requests might be load
>   balanced to other members where the session information does not
>   exist.

Any suggestions?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that each server has a different web.config, all pointing to their own storage instead of sharing a single storage point.